# How to add an method outside to class in ES6 JS

Tags: javascript, class, methods, ecmascript-6

My class is

```
class calculate {
    constructor(l,b) {
        this.l = l;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

I need to add a method called **area** to the above class, is there any way I can add? I tried looking for documentation but i didn't find the correct answer. I would really appreciate if anyone helped me in this.

Comment: By `method outside to class`, do you mean you can't define the method with the class definition, it has to be a separate standalone statement?

Answer (score 2):

A class is *mostly* just syntax sugar for a constructor function and assignments to its prototype. This, for example:

```
class calculate {
   constructor(l, b) {
      this.l = l;
      this.b = b;
   }
   someMethod() {
      
   }
}
```

is mostly equivalent to

```
function calculate(l, b) {
   this.l = l;
   this.b = b;
}
calculate.prototype.someMethod = function () {

};
```

You can assign to the `.prototype` of classes the same way:

```
class calculate {
   constructor(l,b) {
       this.l = l;
       this.b = b;
   }
}
calculate.prototype.area = function() {
   // ...
};
```

(but this is pretty strange to do - this would usually be indicative of smelly code. Consider if you can rework the requirements so that the class constructor and its methods can be defined all at once instead.)